# How does Mac login automatically after software update?

Tags: macos, software-update, login

I have a MacBook Pro running Sonoma (but I think this predates it). FileVault is enabled, so automatic login is prohibited. If I restart normally, it goes to the login screen as expected.

But when I install a software update, as I did last week with 14.4.1, it restarts as part of the installation. But when this finishes, it logs back into my account.

How is it able to do this?